# Crashes 2.79 (GPU)

Tags: rendering, gpu

I have a problem with crashes Blender 2.79 (2.79a, 2.79b and new "experimental") when I want to switch to rendered viewport shading (permanently) and/or add a material (frequently) with Cycles render engine using GPU.

In smaller scenes it reports nothing, just `The program is not working` and running out.

In bigger scenes I see the notification `Nvidia Windows kernel mode driver stopped working and has recovered`

Interesting thing is Blender crashes only on indoors scene (like a room interior), but not outside.

Blender 2.80 and 2.78c work OK.

System: Win8.1, Intel Core i5-4200H, 8 Gb RAM, gtx 860M (4 Gb)

I have done to fix:

- latest nvidia drivers
- switch to maximum perfomans
- vertical sync forced off
- registry fix

But it's still the same.
Is it a bug? Should I report it to developers?

Comment: What you don't say is what kind of scene you are dealing with. If thins happens with complex scenes and not with simple ones it might just mean that you have a scene that is beyond the resources available in your computer.